# Explanation of Bayesian probability

Tags: probability

I'm using the [MultiNomial Naive Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Multinomial_naive_Bayes) algorithm provided by [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html) to predict pos/neg sentences, with words as features.

Where F is feature and V is the pos/neg class, a features informativeness is calculated by:
$$
MAX(P(F^i|V^1)) / P(F^i|V^2)
$$

To clarify: I'm asking how the individual probabilities are calculated for each class, like such:

$$
P(F^i|V^1)
$$
Can someone explain the maths behind how the MultiNomialNB is assigning probabilities for each feature to an individual class? Here is an explanation sourced from this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017288/how-is-most-informative-feature-percentage-is-calculated-in-naive-bayes-nltk-pyt) post:

> The probability of a word given the tag is computed in the train() function using the Expected Likelihood Estimation from the ELEProbDist which is a LidstoneProbDist object under the hood where the gamma argument is set to 0.5, and it does:
>
> class LidstoneProbDist(ProbDistI):
>
> "The Lidstone estimate for the probability distribution of the
>       experiment used to generate a frequency distribution.  The
>       "Lidstone estimate" is parameterized by a real number *gamma*,
>       which typically ranges from 0 to 1.  The Lidstone estimate
>       approximates the probability of a sample with count *c* from an
>       experiment with *N* outcomes and *B* bins as
>       `c+gamma)/(N+B*gamma)`.  This is equivalent to adding
>       *gamma* to the count for each bin, and taking the maximum
>       likelihood estimate of the resulting frequency distribution."

If anyone could provide me with a step-by-step account of how probabilities for features are being calculated in terms of formulas and theory, I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\P{\mathbb{P}}$By Bayes' rule we can compute
$$
\P(y=+|x) = \frac{1}{Z}\P(x|y=+)\P(y=+) = \frac{\P(x|y=+)\P(y=+)}{\P(x|y=-)\P(y=-) + \P(x|y=+)\P(y=+)}.
$$
by Bayes' theorem. On our training data we can easily estimate $\P(y=+)$ as an average, but $\P(x|y=+)=\P(x_1|y=+)\P(x_2|y=1,x_1)\dots\P(x_n|y=1,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})$ is extremely hard to compute.

The Naive Bayes model makes the (naive) assumption that each feature $x_i$ is independent conditional on the outcome $y=+$, from which we have the classifier output
$$
\begin{align*}
\P(y=+|x) &= \frac{\P(y=+)}{Z}\bigl[\P(x_1|y=+)\dots\P(x_n|y=+)\bigr]\\
&= \frac{\P(y=+)\P(x_1|y=+)\dots\P(x_n|y=+)}{\P(y=-)\P(x_1|y=-)\dots\P(x_n|y=-) + \P(y=+)\P(x_1|y=+)\dots\P(x_n|y=+)}.
\end{align*}
$$
Since each conditional probability $\P(x_i | y=\pm)$ of each word in the document can be estimated easily by an average over the training set, this is easy to compute.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Would you be able to phrase that in a 1., 2., 3. kind of format? Im an amatuer so I find the long formulas quite daunting to comprehend.